# Level of encapsulation in JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist

I am working with a project and don't want to give access to the innermost classes. This is the class structure I am using,

```
// data types are not important unless mentioned
class One
{ 
    protected propertyOne;
    protected String id; 
}

class Two
{
    protected ArrayList<One> arrayOne;
    protected String id;
}

class Three
{
    protected ArrayList<Two> arrayTwo;
    protected otherProperty;
}
```

Now, main class will instantiate Three and should use Two and One through member methods. If I return any of `ArrayList` through get function, all the data can be easily changed from anywhere. So instead of `ArrayList<Two>`, I am returning `ArrayList<Two.id>` and then another method is called with particular `Two.id`. This takes care of keeping `ArrayList`s hidden but generates lots of code and extra objects because of `ArrayList<Two.id>` and `ArrayList<One.id>`.

In C++, I would have made a `const` method with `const` return type to ensure no changes in `ArrayList`.

Is there any smart way in Java to keep `ArrayList`s hidden?

Comment: You can provide getter methods which return e.g. `Collections.unmodifiableList(arrayTwo)` to prevent callers from modifying `arrayTwo`.

Comment: I'd make everything `private` rather than `protected`, too. `protected` allows access to other classes in the same package, and subclasses.

Comment: [`Collections.<T>unmodifiableList(List<T>)`?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-)

Comment: _"I am returning `ArrayList<Two.id>`..."_ -- this is not meaningful in Java. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: What do you mean by "If I return any of `ArrayList` through get function, all the data can be easily changed from anywhere."? If you return an `ArrayList` then you can modify its elements, if you return an element of an `ArrayList` then you can't modify the other elements.

Comment: @Andy Turner & Turing85, thanks for both of your suggestions. Jim Garrison, I used it as a shorthand of "ArrayList<String> with Two.id as values". Jonny Henly, there are at least two ArrayLists and I want both of them immutable.

Comment: Even through the unmodifiableList underlying objects can be modified through setters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a similar issue with a hibernate based API. We wanted to make "accidential" change impossible, enforcing the use of services to keep the business logic in one place and enforcing some access control on the API level.

We did resolve this with proxies and a derived Readonly interface.

So if you have a property in `Two`, the `getX` method is declared in a `ReadonlyTwo` interface. Whenever you return a list of `Two`, you declare the list to be of `ReadonlyTwo`. The programmer can hack around this by learning the API and he will see, when the object is really `Two` and can be typecasted. If you want to avoid that, you would have to wrap a proxy around the real `Two` object, implementing the `ReadonlyTwo` interface.

If you now return the lists as immutable lists, your API is pretty safe from external modification, even down to the object level.

```
// data types are not important unless mentioned
class One implements ReadonlyOne
{ 
    protected propertyOne;
    protected String id; 
}

class Two implements ReadonlyTwo
{
    protected ArrayList<? extends ReadonlyOne> arrayOne;
    protected String id;
}

class Three implements ReadonlyThree
{
    protected ArrayList<? extends ReadonlyTwo> arrayTwo;
    protected otherProperty;
}
```

Interfaces look like this (you did not add any getter/setter methods, so I make them up here):

```
interface ReadonlyThree {
    List<? extends ReadonlyTwo>getArrayTwo();   
}
```

Your application objects requires business methods to handle the modification of `Two` and `One` objects:

```
interface ThreeService {
    ReadonlyTwo addTwo(p1, p2, p3) throws BusinessException;
    void removeTwo(ReadonlyTwo twoRO) throws BusinessException;
    List<? extends ReadonlyTwo>findTwoByPredicate(Predicate p) throws BusinessException;
}
```

Comment: Your method "getArrayTwo()" returns a wild card.   Would returning List<T extends ReadonlyTwo> getArrayTwo();  would be sufficient.

Comment: @Teto: agreed, yet, this is just the concept.

Comment: Sorry.  I mean to word my comment as a question.  Would returning List<T extends ReadonlyTwo>  be sufficient?    I agree with your solution for protecting the contents of the array.  I have used similar strategies myself.  Understood it is just proof of concept.

Comment: If you have a T, you can use it, in that case you would declare T as extending Readonly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have few doubts. a. I can't seem to do 'arrayTwo.add(new Two())'. b. I don't get how the returned list is immutable. Why can't I just change it through iterators? Thank you again.

Comment: I got answer to, why can't I add to arrayTwo. Still I do need to put objects in there and I have not yet found how. All the explanations are about why is it not possible to add objects to generic collection but then how can I initialise the list? Is the generic collection only good to pass as an argument but not as class variable?

Comment: The list is immutable, because you return it as immutable list as proposed in the comments to your question. To add stuff to the list, you need service methods (see ThreeService). Remove yourself from the mindset of the datastructure. Try to think in semantics, not syntax: What are you doing, not how: If Three is Order, Two may be OrderItem. OrderService has a method `addItem(String itemKey, int amount)` and `addItem(String title, String description, double price, int amount, double discount)`. The actual adding is none of Order-users business.

Comment: @thst, I totally get your point about semantics. And truth is, I am getting lost in the implementation. If I create ArrayList<? extends ReadonlyTwo>, I can't add to it. On the other hand, if I create ArrayList<ReadonlyTwo> and return it as List<? extends ReadonlyTwo>, I can still typecast it to Two and access any set functions. I want to provide only service functions which will internally manipulate the ArrayList by setters but still be able to return ArrayList so its getters can be accessed to display data. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: @thst, I worked out interfaces, and the ArrayList is immutable. I am not able to avoid typecasting it to actual object though. Can you please elaborate on proxy wrap?

Comment: You understand, that you will never get full security on the class level? If you let someone share the JDK with you, it will be very hard to sandbox him. You are on your way to create Applet Runtime V2. Having said that, you can find many tutorials on using proxies (one example: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-proxies.html). Basically, what the proxy does: It creates a "pseudo" object, that will be exposed as the interface you choose (Readonly in your case). An Invocation handler forwards the method calls to the real thing (or does sth completely different).

Comment: If you use proxies, you will have to fill the list with proxies. You cannot use the same list inside and outside any more.

Comment: @thst, Thank for the pointers. I thought it is a design pattern for Java. The interfaces work very well.